# nodejs zlib inflate the hexa buffer

Tags: node.js, zlib, inflate

I have a Buffer of type hex.

I am not able to inflate this buffer with zlib. It is returning incorrect header check.

Please find the below implementation :

```
var actualOutput = new Buffer("0130c21164300028","hex");
var actOut = actualOutput.toString('hex');
console.log(actOut);
var actBuff = new Buffer(actOut,'base64');
zlib.inflate(actBuff, function(err, actBuff) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(actOut+'\ninflate\n'+actBuff.toString()+'\n');
  }else{
    console.log('\ninflate error:\n'+err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where did you get that hex string from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to pass `actualOutput` directly into `zlib.inflate`.

In the code you currently have, you are forming a Buffer from the hex string, converting that Buffer back into a hex string, **decoding the hex string as base64**, then passing that Buffer into `zlib.inflate`. The resulting Buffer will have corrupted information.

Comment: Good call, although that's only part of the problem (because even with using the correct buffer, it can't be inflated).

Comment: In that case, the original hex string isn't valid data, or wasn't compressed using deflate?

Comment: Hence my comment asking where the data is coming from ;D

Comment: Welp, didn't see that. Sorry :P